# Why isn't my jsangular looping through my scope?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I'm learning directives and controllers in JSAngular. Currently I'm just trying to get the appetizers to loop through on the menu but can't seem to get the output to respond. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

MainController.js:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.today = new Date();

  $scope.appetizers = [
    {
      name: 'Caprese',
      description: 'Mozzarella, tomatoes, basil, balsmaic glaze.',
      price: 4.95
    },
    {
      name: 'Bruschetta',
      description: 'Grilled bread garlic, tomatoes, olive oil.',
      price: 4.95
    },
    {
      name: 'Mozzarella Sticks',
      description: 'Served with marinara sauce.',
      price: 3.95
    }
  ];

  $scope.mains = [
    {
      name: 'Roast Beef Au Jus',
      description: 'Delicious Amazing Sauce',
      price: 15.99
    },
    {
      name: 'Prime Rib',
      description: 'Just like Jacoby/s',
      price: 18.95
    },
    {
      name: 'BBQ Ribs',
      description: 'Better than Krupa/s',
      price: 15.99
    }
  ]

  $scope.extras = [
    {
      name: 'Cole slaw',
    },
    {
      name: 'Creamed Spinach',
    },
    {
      name: 'Boston Baked Beans',
    }
  ]

}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic,700italic|Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='PizzaPlanetApp'>
    <div class="header">
      <h1><span>Pizza</span><span>Planet</span></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Specials for {{ today | date }}</h1>
        <h2>Appetizers</h2>
        <div class="appetizers row" ng-repeat="appetizer in appetizers">
          <div class="item col-md-9">
            <h3 class="name"> {{ appetizer.name }} </h3>
            <p class="description"> {{ appetizer.description }} </p>
          </div>
          <div class="price col-md-3">
            <p class="price"> {{ appetizers.price | currency }} </p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <pizza-footer></pizza-footer>
    </div>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors on console? Is maincontroller.js included in index.html?

Comment: check your console. It says `app is not defined`

Comment: I suspect you forgot to reference your app module in your MainController.js file. var app = angular.module("PizzaPlanetApp");  before doing the app.controller() call can you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to refer to your `PizzaPlanetApp` application module first. Add the following line of code before creating the controller.

```
var app = angular.module("PizzaPlanetApp", []);
```

This refers to the app you want to create the controller of and contains the list of modules your app depends on.

In your case the list is empty.

[***jsfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/6ohuhm5t/)

Comment: He probably just need reference the app module with the getter, rather than redefine it as he is already including the app.js file at the bottom of the body.

Comment: Thanks guys! I did have that in an app.js, but there was a spelling error!